# Does replit uses ssh?

Tags: ssh, terminal, openssh

[Replit's](https://replit.com/languages/cpp) terminal provides a lot of features that are very similar to any Linux terminal. At first, I thought the site was using SSH to link a remote terminal to the website but when I ran the following command `service ssh status`, then the output was
`* sshd is not running`. This indicates that the site is not using SSH to link the terminal.
[image: SSH not running]

Does this mean the developers have created a custom terminal for their website or is there a way to show this output for remote users for security purposes?